# Why does the following code give different answers?

Tags: c

I have the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  time_t t2 = rawtime;
  if(rawtime == t2) printf("Hi %ul %ul\n", rawtime, t2);

  return(0);
}
```

When this code is run, the printf gives different answers for rawtime and t2. Why is that? Could somebody please help?

Comment: You are accessing uninitialized variables. That is undefined behavior.

Comment: You are basically asking why `int a; printf("%d", a)` is different every time.

Comment: Did you mean the result is different in different execution? Or in 1 execution rawtime & t2 is different?

Comment: Yes. My question is why rawtime not equal to t2. I am not asking why it is different in different executions. I am especially confused because the condition "(rawtime == t2)" is true.

Comment: @anupamb In that case, it should be the same, I can't think why not.

Comment: @anupamb Your code has a bug that causes it not to do what you expect. Fix the bug and they mystery will go away.

Comment: It's not. That's the problem. I am using Visual Studio 2010, if that matters.

Comment: Your question is basically "why should two variables that both hold a value that was never initialized not compare as equal". And the answer is simply that there's no reason why they should, so any result is reasonable.

Comment: @David Schwartz Is the bug in the printf part?

Comment: @anupamb It's everywhere. Yes, it's in `printf` too because that reads variables whose value has not been initialized.

Comment: @David Schwartz I thought it gets initialized to some unknow value (not in the hands of the programmer). But whatever that value is, it should remain so, when the variable is assigned to another. Isn't that correct?

Comment: If it is unknown, how can you expect it to not be same? It can be same, or not same, or in a quantum state being same and not same at the same time. :)

Comment: @anupamb Short answer: No, but for very complex reasons. If you don't want to understand register caching and trap representations, just think of it as really being uninitialized. See my answer.

Comment: @anupamb On linux, with gcc, each time run your code, the result is the same. But u are using windows, I think there are implementation differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why they don't compare as equal:

1. `rawtime` is not initialized.
2. Either `t2` is initialized or it is not.
3. If `t2` is initialized, then we are comparing an initialized value to an uninitialized value. There's no reason to expect these to compare as equal.
4. If `t2` is uninitialized, we are comparing two uninitialized variables. There's no reason to expect these to compare as equal
5. So either way, there's no reason to expect these to compare as equal.

To expect them to compare as equal, you have to invent some odd state for `t2` to be in that's, I don't even know what, initialized to an unspecified value? Uninitialized but guaranteed to compare equal to another uninitialized value? Or what?

Whatever thought process lead you to expect these to compare as equal, it is incomprehensible to me.

By the way, trying to glean this from the C standard is extremely difficult. It comes from a very obscure rule -- "If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined."

It's much easier to just understand that it really is uninitialized than to try to understand the complex rules for when it's guaranteed to have an unspecified value and when it's not. You have to learn about trap representations and other complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to look into this problem from a memory perspective too. The variable is already allocated a memory address (which is not changing). So I believe the 32 (or 64 bits) in that location are something (although uninitialized). I may be wrong in assuming that the '=' is doing some bit-level assignment to another variable (here t2), but that may be a naive mistake. I will try to have a better understanding of uninitialized variable. Thanks!

Comment: @anupamb Why do you say it's allocated a memory address? It never has a value assigned and its address is never taken. So when do you think it's assigned an address?! What operation do you think takes place that requires it to be assigned a memory address as opposed to, for example, being kept in a register for its entire life?

Comment: That's correct. My supposition is not necessarily correct. But I am guessing whether or not it's allocated memory (when just declared) is a compiler thing.

Comment: @anupamb: On a conventional machine, your suppositions are basically correct.  On a conventional machine, "uninitialzed" means "unpredictable, essentially random, might change from run to run, can't depend on it".  But it does not typically mean that the uninitialized value cannot even be inspected or copied.  David Schwartz's answers, though theoretically correct, refer to the abstract language of the C standard and to unusual concepts such as "trap representations" which are almost certainly not a factor on the machine you're using today.

Comment: @SteveSummit The thing is, he is specifically asking about a case where the atypical behavior is observed. So your choices are to either understand the unusual concepts to make sense of the C standard language or use common sense reasoning about a purely abstract machine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Unless it's just a `%ul` vs. `%lu` problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing uninitialized variables. That is undefined behavior.

---

**why it is different in different executions. I am especially confused because the condition "(rawtime == t2)" is true.**

There is not any question of *why*, when there is an undefined behavior being invoked. The variables have been declared and are thus having a place in the memory. That place could contain garbage value from previous program execution, or any other value. It might also happen that the values somehow, by some co-incident are same for those 2 variables, so your `if()` condition is coming as `True`.

But all these things on one side, one cannot question the flow of a program or statement when it is invoking undefined behavior, because to question is to query in the standards, and when the standard itself does not define it, where will anyone get an explanation from.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, yes, since `rawtime` is uninitialized, the behavior is undefined, and all bets are off.  Demons could fly out of your computer's nose, for all the Standard cares.

But on the other hand, `rawtime` is just an integer.  Maybe 64 bits, probably 32 bits.  There are either 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> ordinary values.  There are no trap representations (on any computer you are at all likely to be using.)  So whatever random value starts out in `rawtime` gets copied to `t2`.  So they pretty much have to compare equal, so `printf` pretty much has to be called.  All right so far.

So if `printf` gets called on account of `rawtime` and `t2` being equal, how could they print as unequal?  Probably because you accidentally used `%ul` instead of `%lu`.  Your two format specifiers might be printing the top and bottom halves of `rawtime` (which are probably unequal) and not printing `t2` at all.  Try changing `%ul` to `%lu` and see what happens.

[Disclaimer.  This has been a real-world answer, not a Standard-thumping answer.  If you look only at the Standard, it is indeed meaningless to ask what a program does after its behavior has become undefined.  And there are now compilers that will let themselves do some pretty bizarre things when your program is undefined and they're allowed to.  It's very hard to imagine that a compiler would emit code which (a) copied a bit pattern but then either (b1) compared it unequal or (b2) compared it equal but printed it unequal, but it's not *completely* out of the question.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helps. Yes changing the format specifier changed things, but it wasn't lu that gave the right answer, it was lld. Thanks!